# JavaScript code works on IE but not Safari (Mac or Windows)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, safari, mobile-safari

Can anyone tell me why this wouldn't work on Safari?

```
// Set the height of the iFrame
var avail = document.parentWindow.screen.availHeight;
var screenTop = document.parentWindow.screenTop;
var divHeight = $('.header').css('height').replace('px','');
var divTop = $('.header').position().top;
alert('avail: ' + avail + '\nscreenTop: ' + screenTop + '\ndivHeight: ' + divHeight + '\ndivTop: ' + divTop);
$('#viewerFrame').css('height', (avail - screenTop - divTop - divHeight - 94) + 'px');
```

In IE, it works exactly as I want (which means it sizes the iFrame to take up all of the screen that's left after I take into account the size of the window, the header, and so forth...). Why doesn't it work in Safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.parentWindow is IE-only.
```

You may use `top` or `parent` instead

Comment: This is important to note too. Whenever there's a discrepancy between IE and other browsers, it's often due to IE using a different keyword than what is W3C-compliant. This is becoming less of a problem with newer versions of IE fortunately.

Comment: So, should I use something like `var avail = document.parentWindow.screen.availHeight || document.parent.screen.availHeight`?